# Can't access variables from dynamically loaded javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, variables, loading

I'm using a fairly simple system to load javascript dynamically:

```
include = function (url) {
  var e = document.createElement("script");
  e.src = url;
  e.type="text/javascript";
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e);
};
```

Let's say I have a file test.js which has the following contents:

```
var foo = 4;
```

Now, in my original script, I want to use

```
include(test.js);
console.log(foo);
```

However, I get a 'foo has not been defined' error on this. I'm guessing it has to do with the dynamic script being included as the last child of the `<head>` tag. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is one problem, but it also takes time for the browser to download and parse the remote JS file — and it hasn't done that before you call `console.log`.

You need to delay things until the script has loaded.

This is easiest done by letting a library do the heavy lifting, jQuery has a [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) method that lets you pass a callback to run when the script has loaded.

Answer (score 5):

It is because you have to wait for the script to load. It is not synchronous like you would think. This may work for you:

```
include = function (url, fn) {
    var e = document.createElement("script");
    e.onload = fn;
    e.src = url;
    e.async=true;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e);
};

include("test.js",function(){
    console.log(foo);
});
```

Comment: Nice simple script. But how can we incorporate failure events (like connection not established, or 404 etc) in this..