# Implement 'error' callback for Dynamically loaded javascript file

Tags: javascript

I am loading javascript dynamically and accessing its variable. I checked the **second** answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736943/cant-access-variables-from-dynamically-loaded-javascript) and the following code works beautifully.

```
include = function (url, fn) {
    var e = document.createElement("script");
    e.onload = fn;
    e.src = url;
    e.async=true;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e);
};

include("test.js",function(){
    console.log(foo);
});
```

**QUESTION:** I want to have a `onFailure` callback function as well that allows me to process code in case

- The internet is down.
- The filename is not accessible (eg: incorrect path)

Will appreciate if someone can guide me to the right direction.
Thanks

Comment: The [MDN page for the HTMLScriptElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement) has [a good example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement#Dynamically_importing_scripts) which you can build off.

Comment: Yeah that example works fine for me. Neat solution. Thanks

Comment: Added it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MDN page for the HTMLScriptElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement) has [a good example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement#Dynamically_importing_scripts) which you can build off.

```
function loadError (oError) {
  throw new URIError("The script " + oError.target.src + " is not accessible.");
}

function importScript (sSrc, fOnload) {
  var oScript = document.createElement("script");
  oScript.type = "text\/javascript";
  oScript.onerror = loadError;
  if (fOnload) { oScript.onload = fOnload; }
  document.currentScript.parentNode.insertBefore(oScript, document.currentScript);
  oScript.src = sSrc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution is to actually use an XMLHttpRequest. This gives you access to the status of the request after it completes, where the "load" event does not. For simplicity, I'll illustrate with jQuery, but this can be written in vanilla javascript as well.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"myfile.js",
    method:"GET",
    dataType:"html",
    success: function(data, status, jqxhr) {
                 console.log("It worked");

                 // This can be very dangerous. Make sure you trust script source.
                 var newScript = $("<script>").html(data);
                 $('body').append(newScript);
             },
    error: function(jqxhr, status, error) {
               console.log("Oh no!");
           }
});
```

More on the jQuery ajax request [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).